# Time-dependent color shifting with Tkinter (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'd like to write a program that over a given time period fades the background of a [Tkinter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) window from an initial hex color to a final hex color while displaying some of the colors in between. (Uncommenting line 99, `print time, hex_color_t`, should clarify what I mean if it isn't clear.)

Here's the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import re

class InvalidColor(Exception):
    pass

def color_to_hex(color):
    MIN_COLOR = 0
    MAX_COLOR = 255
    try:
        if color >= MIN_COLOR and color <= MAX_COLOR:
            try:
                hex_str = hex(color)[2:]
            except TypeError:
                raise InvalidColor
            if len(hex_str) < 2:
                hex_str = "0" + hex_str
            return hex_str
        else:
            raise InvalidColor
    except InvalidColor:
        return "00"

def rgb_to_hex((red, green, blue), upper = True):
    r = color_to_hex(red)
    g = color_to_hex(green)
    b = color_to_hex(blue)
    hex_str = "#%s%s%s" % (r, g, b)
    if upper:
        hex_str = hex_str.upper()
    return hex_str

def hex_to_rgb(hex_value):
    hex_pattern = re.compile(r"^(#)?(?P<r>[a-f0-9]{2})(?P<g>[a-f0-9]{2})(?P<b>[a-f0-9]{2})$", re.IGNORECASE)

    match = hex_pattern.match(hex_value)

    HEX_PREFIX = "0x"
    BASE = 16

    if match:
        # could be more DRY-ish, but whatever
        r = int(HEX_PREFIX + match.group("r"), BASE)
        g = int(HEX_PREFIX + match.group("g"), BASE)
        b = int(HEX_PREFIX + match.group("b"), BASE)
    else:
        raise InvalidColor

    return (r, g, b)

#print rgb_to_hex((255, 0, 0))
#print type(hex_to_rgb(rgb_to_hex((107,142,35))))
#print hex_to_rgb("4B0082")


root = Tk()

initial_color_hex = "#0000ff" # blue
final_color_hex = "#44ccff" # light blue

STOP_TIME_MS = 2000
STEP_TIME_MS = 50

"""
def final_color(*args, **kwargs):
    root.configure(background = final_color_hex)
"""

def set_color(root, hex_color, *args, **kwargs):
    root.configure(background = hex_color)

def linear_fade(root,
         hex_start_color,
         hex_stop_color,
         stop_time_ms = STOP_TIME_MS,
         step_time_ms = STEP_TIME_MS,
         delay_ms = 0):

    root.configure(background = hex_start_color)
    (r0, g0, b0) = hex_to_rgb(hex_start_color)
    (rf, gf, bf) = hex_to_rgb(hex_stop_color)

    delta_r = rf-r0
    delta_g = gf-g0
    delta_b = bf-b0

    #print delta_r, delta_g, delta_b

    for time in range(delay_ms, stop_time_ms+1, step_time_ms):
        rt = r0 + (delta_r * time // stop_time_ms)
        gt = g0 + (delta_g * time // stop_time_ms)
        bt = b0 + (delta_b * time // stop_time_ms)
        #print (rt, gt, bt)
        hex_color_t = rgb_to_hex((rt,gt,bt))
        #print time, hex_color_t
        root.after(time, set_color(root, hex_color_t))

root.configure(background = initial_color_hex)
#root.after(1000, final_color)

root.geometry("400x400")

linear_fade(root, initial_color_hex, final_color_hex)

root.mainloop()
```

So far it seems to be going through the `for` loop without making the window, so I just end up with a delay and then the final color as the background.

I suppose I should go for a more minimal working example. I tried:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

initial_color_hex = "#0000ff" # blue
final_color_hex = "#44ccff" # light blue

def set_color(hex_color, *args, **kwargs):
    root.configure(background = hex_color)

root.configure(background = initial_color_hex)
root.after(1000, set_color(final_color_hex))

root.geometry("400x400")

root.mainloop()
```

But I still encounter the same problem. I did find something that sort of works somewhere, which was:

```
try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

def grey(*args,**kwargs):
    root.configure(background = "grey")

def bthing():
    root.configure(background = "red")
    root.after(1000, grey)

tkinter.Button(text = "OK", command = bthing).pack()

root.configure(background = "grey")
root.geometry("400x400")

root.mainloop()
```

But what is the critical difference between these two examples?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I change the background color of a frame as a function of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
root.after(time, set_color(root, hex_color_t))
```

does not do what you think it does.  This line **immediately** evaluates the `set_color` function with the arguments `root` and `hex_color_t`.  It then takes the result (which incidentally is `None` in this case) and schedules the result to be evaluated in `time` ms (needless to say, evaluating `None` does not affect the color of the root window).

This explains why your window immediately changes color - your code causes all the color changes immediately one after another, then executes a series of meaningless scheduled evaluations.

You can fix this by doing this:

```
def createColorChangeFunction(hcolor):
    return lambda:set_color(root, hcolor)
root.after(time, createColorChangeFunction(hex_color_t))
```

The `createColorChangeFunction` is necessary so the various lambda functions have their own local reference to a hex color, rather than sharing one.

I tested this change and got a window fading slowly from dark to light blue.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed -- with an explanation for why it works to boot.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help.  If this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted, so future readers can easily tell.